# Как в таблице вывести дату в нужном формате у последнего загруженного файла?

Tags: java, datetime

В конце кода я возвращаю в колонку таблицы дату последнего вложенного файла, но формат даты выводится так "The Aug 26 16:45:55 SAMT 2021". Я хочу сделать другой вывод "dd.mm.yyyy" , как это возможно осуществить?
Вот код:

```
@Override
public Component generateCell(T entity) {
    String dataLastAttachment = "";
    List<CardAttachment> attachments = entity.getAttachments();

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(attachments)) {
        CardAttachment attachment = attachments.get(attachments.size() - 1);
        dataLastAttachment = attachment.getCreateTs().toString();
    }

    return new Table.PlainTextCell(dataLastAttachment);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно отформатировать дату/таймстемп, которые возвращаются из метода `createTs`, используя нужный формат.

Для этого можно применить либо `SimpleDateFormat`, если `createTs` возвращает экземпляр класса `java.util.Date`:

```java
import java.text.*;

// ...
@Override
public Component generateCell(T entity) {
    String dataLastAttachment = "";
    List<CardAttachment> attachments = entity.getAttachments();

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(attachments)) {

        CardAttachment attachment = attachments.get(attachments.size() - 1);

        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

        dataLastAttachment = sdf.format(attachment.getCreateTs());
    }

    return new Table.PlainTextCell(dataLastAttachment);
}
```

---

Если метод `createTs()` возвращает экземпляр `Instant` / `ZonedDateTime` / `LocalDateTime` из Java Date/Time API, для форматирования следует использовать `DateTimeFormatter` с аналогичным паттерном (в случае `Instant` нужно обязательно задать часовой пояс):

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

// ...

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(attachments)) {
        // предполагается что список отсортирован по дате
        CardAttachment attachment = attachments.get(attachments.size() - 1);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu")
            .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        dataLastAttachment = formatter.format(attachment.getCreateTs());
    }
```